# File server.js is being edited (by root with nano 2.4.2, PID xxxx); continue?

Tags: ubuntu, nano

I am on Ubuntu 15.10 x64. When I am trying to edit server.js file, it is opening a blank nano editor and displaying 
**"File server.js is being edited (by root with nano 2.4.2, PID xxxx); continue?"**
with options - Yes, No, Cancel.

I copied a backup file on this file but still I am getting the same message.

Could you please suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: Check with tools like `ps` and `htop` whether this other `nano` instance is still running. If it's not, there's most likely a hidden dotfile in the same folder which leads `nano` to believe that the other instance is still running (at least `vim` works this way, I don't use `nano`; try `ls -lA` and look for a file that begins with `.server.js` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you very much Martin. There was a .server.js.swp in the same directory. Deleting it worked. Can you you please post your comment as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check with tools like `ps` and `htop` whether this other `nano` instance is still running. If it's not, there's most likely a hidden dotfile in the same folder which leads `nano` to believe that the other instance is still running (at least vim works this way, I don't use `nano`; try `ls -lA` and look for a file that begins with `.server.js` or something like that.

Comment: In my case, an ssh connection was interrupted while editing `FILE.txt`. nano saved a snapshot in `FILE.txt.save` and some sort of lock file called `.FILE.txt.swp` (note the `.` at the beginning).  Deleting the lock file fixed the issue, overwriting the file with the `.save` version restored my changes.

Comment: Use `screen` or `tmux` in the future, no more trouble from interrupted SSH sessions :)

Answer (score 13):

In addition, if you're the only user on that machine and you're sure that you don't have an open editor on that file in another window, you can just accept nano's offer to continue, it will remove the leftover swap file, saving you a few steps.

Comment: Best answer! Thanks!

Comment: this happen when network is disconnected then reconnect terminal for example "termius" , so this is not double login or how ? do we need force logout current something like that ?

Comment: Hmm, I don't really understand your wording. Your situation is exactly that which I described - you know you don't have another editor open on the same file because that terminal was closed, so you can just continue editing the file in the new nano.

Answer (score 6):

On my Ubuntu Linux server it gives me an option to hop back into the stopped nano job:

```
Use "fg" to return to nano.
```

So, you could try to simply type `fg`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This saved me from when i accidentally used ctrl+z in nano

Comment: never use fg but this answer is the best.

Answer (score 0):

I was editing a file called `serial.c` and ran into that problem. I backed the file up using `cp serial.c serial2.c` and then deleted the original with `rm serial.c`. Issuing a `nano serial.c` still returned the error, even though the file didn't exist. Performing an `ls -lA` revealed that there was a hidden swapfile called `.serial.c.swp`, which I deleted using `rm .serial.c.swp`. Then I was able to rename my `serial2.c` back to `serial.c` using `mv serial2.c serial.c`, and now I'm able to edit the file without the conflict.

Comment: This is basically a rehash of the accepted answer, augmented by the *specifics* of your experience. For future reference, renaming the file is unnecessary; just delete the ``.swp`` file.